# How to convert date-time srings from different timezones into integer to find most recent i.e. maximum of integer in perl?

Tags: perl

I have date-time strings in the below format

```
[yyyymmddhhmmss+TZ] "20110711114445+08", "20110711114445+05.30".
```

How should i find out which is most recent date-time string ?
I want all of the string to convert into a single time-zone and then convert the strings into integer to find out maximum integer.
Help me out ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) to parse the date-time strings into [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) objects. Once you have the objects, you can compare them as ordinary integers.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use List::Util 'max';

my $Strp = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(pattern => '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%z');
my @objects = map $Strp->parse_datetime($_), @strings;
my $dt = max(@objects);
```

Comment: @black: Most date handling can be done with any of Date::Calc, DateManip, or DateTime; everyone should be familiar with at least one of these.  (That said, the DateTime family certainly covers ground that the others don't)

Comment: @ysth: yes, I always use `Date::Calc`. I just meant that `DateTime::Format::Strptime` is more specific for the current task, after watching its reference on CPAN.

Comment: @mandy, Note: `max` didn't always obey operator overloading, so the code will fail with older versions of List::Util.

Answer (score 1):

The [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Date-Calc-6.3/lib/Date/Calc.pod) can help you.